# Dividing a rectangle into NxM rectangle and numbering them in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, coordinates

So I have a rectangle of size 104x68 and I have divided the rectangle into 36 equal parts. The numbers in the image represent the coordinate location for each small rectangles.

[image]

Now I want to number each rectangle, something like the below image:

[image]

i.e.

```
For coordinate location x = [0, 17.3] and y = [0, 11.3] will be number 1 box
For coordinate location x = (17.3, 34.6] and y = [0, 11.3] will be number 2 box
....
For coordinate location x = (86.6, 104] and y = (56.6, 68] will be number 36 box
```

After numbering each of the boxes, I want that: given a value say (54,35) the program will yield the box number for that particular value, for the given value (54, 35) box number will be 22.

What is the optimized way of solving this problem in Python? Can somebody help?

Comment: It's easier to optimize your approach after you have working code. What have you tried so far, even if it's not optimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, you can get the rectangle number by inputting the required parameters. `weight` and `height` show the dimensions of the rectangle (in your example, `width = 104, height = 68`). `xpartition` and `ypartition` parameters show the number of divisions in each dimension (in your example, 36 equally division means `xpartition = 6, ypartition = 6`). `xinput` and `yinput` are dimensions of the queried point which is desired to know its rectanlge number in the specified division (in your example, `xinput = 54, yinput = 35`).

```
import math
def get_rect_num(width, height, xpartition, ypartition, xinput, yinput):
    x_step = width / xpartition
    y_step = height / ypartition
    x = math.ceil((xinput if xinput > 0 else 0.5) / x_step) # handle border cases as well
    y = math.ceil((yinput if yinput > 0 else 0.5) / y_step)  # handle border cases as well
    return (y-1) * xpartition + x

get_rect_num(104, 68, 6, 6, 54, 35)

#> 22
```

The time complexity of the above computation is in `Theta(1)` based on the four primary operations.

Comment: Note that this doesn't give the desired result on the border, when x or y is zero. A possible workaround would be `x = math.floor(xinput * .999999 / x_step)`, similar for `y` and then returning `y * xpartition + x + 1`.

Comment: @JohanC right. Or handle the border as a separate case.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most optimised way (you could use `itertools`), but a fairly compact way to do this is just with `numpy.arange`. Assuming that this is your actual task, I can't see why the method would need to be more optimal than this.

```
import numpy as np 
SMALL_NUM = 1e-5 
def range_pairs(max_value, divisions): 
    division_length = max_value/divisions 
    range_values = list(np.arange(0, max_value+SMALL_NUM, division_length)) 
    return [(range_values[i], range_values[i+1]) for i in range(divisions)] 
 
i = 0 
for y in range_pairs(68, 6): 
    for x in range_pairs(104, 6): 
        i += 1 
        print(f"For coordinate location x = {x} and y = {y} will be number {i} box")
```

For larger tasks, consider `itertools`, and also consider pre-calculating the `range_pairs` below, or putting an `lru_cache` on the the `range_pairs` function.